# I want loop data output on the screen using kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to kivy and python. I'm working on an application to connect with the Elm327 later save the replies for debugging.
I want start with getting the loop output on the screen after pressing the button. Unable to do that.

I have tried searching but couldn't find a proper solution.
Also tried Label: and get output.
Under the start button i want the loop open when start button is pressed in the fifth window.
I have constructed different screens a i will be getting different outputs in each screen and perform different task.
Here 'n' is the variable which output i needed.

.py file

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MainWindow(Screen):

    def bt1(self):
        print("Select Adaper")

    def bt2(self):
        print("Connect to ELM327")

    def bt3(self):
        print("Send AT Commands")

    def bt4(self):
        print("Start Loop")


class SecondWindow(Screen, Widget):
    pass


class ThirdWindow(Screen, Widget):
    pass

class FourthWindow(Screen, Widget):
    pass

class FifthWindow(Screen, Widget):

    def looP(self):
        n = 2099
        for _ in range(200):
            n += 1
            if n > 2199:
                print("Stopping")
                break

            print(n)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
    ThirdWindow:
    FourthWindow:
    FifthWindow:

<Button>:
    font_size:20
    color:1,1,1,1
    size_hint: 1, 0.25

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    FloatLayout:


        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1}
            text: 'Select Adapter'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "second"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.bt1()

        Button:
            id: btn
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.75}
            text: 'Connect to Elm327'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "third"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.bt2()

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.5}
            text: 'Send AT commands'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "fourth"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.bt3()

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.25}
            text: 'Loop'
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "fifth"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.bt4()



<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"

    FloatLayout:

        Widget:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1

                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.1}
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Go back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"



<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "third"

    FloatLayout:

        Widget:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1

                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.1}
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Go back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<FourthWindow>:
    name: "fourth"

    FloatLayout:

        Widget:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1

                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.1}
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Go back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<FifthWindow>:
    name: "fifth"

    FloatLayout:
        Widget:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1

                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1}
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Start"
            on_release:
                root.looP()

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.1}
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Go back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Comment: `your text` please could you  `your text` format your code `your text` properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a widget (perhaps a `TextInput`) to display the output to your `kv`. Something like this:

```
    TextInput:
        id: input
        readonly: True
        size_hint: 1, 0.8
        pos_hint: {'top':0.9}
```

in your `<FifthWindow>` rule. Then add the output to that widget in your `looP()` method:

```
def looP(self):
    n = 2099
    for _ in range(200):
        n += 1
        if n > 2199:
            print("Stopping")
            break

        print(n)
        self.ids.input.text += str(n) + '\n'  # add output to the GUI
```